# Создание комплекта в qt creator

Tags: c++, qtcreator

Начинаю учиться программировать на c ++ и скачал ide qt creator. Не понимаю как создать и использовать комплекты.Помогите пж.Систему сборки выбрал CMake[image]

Comment: лучше переключите интерфейс на английский и читайте сайт qt